# No user registration on login screen

Tags: registration, aspnetboilerplate, user-registration

Just got the ASP.NET Boilerplate project up and running and the login screen comes up fine, but there is no option to register a new user on the login screen.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-registration is disabled for host users.

You can change to the tenant named `Default`, or modify `AccountController.IsSelfRegistrationEnabled`.

```cs
private bool IsSelfRegistrationEnabled()
{
    if (!AbpSession.TenantId.HasValue)
    {
        // Comment out the line below to enable self-registration for host users
        return false; // No registration enabled for host users!
    }

    return true;
}
```